# Git use commits of master in multiple branches

Tags: git, git-branch, gitkraken

I have a master branch with multiple child branches. Each child branch has a small difference compared to the master branch. I often run into the case that I update my master branch and would like the child branches take that update/commit as well. How do I accomplish this is a good clean way?

Currently I am using Gitkraken for this case, so solutions with Gitkraken are welcome as well.

Comment: How about merging master into those other branches?

Comment: ...or rebasing all other branches to be on top of master again?

Comment: @NilsWerner ok but I am a Little confused to I have to rebase the branch onto or into the master?

Comment: `git checkout branch && git rebase master`...

Comment: @NilsWerner So I went into the master branch and git rebased onto the other branch now the other branch contains the changes of my master branch which is correct. So Does this way seems legit? (Gitkraken says "gitrebase onto when I drop the master branch onto the other branch")

Answer (score 1):

#### If you want all master commits to be merged

```
git checkout feature/my-feature-branch1
git merge master
```

You can also consider [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) instead of merging, for keeping the history clean.

#### If you want only to apply a subset of commits from master to the branches

```
git log # For figuring out the SHA-1 hashes you want to apply
git checkout feature/my-feature-branch1
git cherry-pick <SHA-COMMIT-1> <SHA-COMMIT-2> <SHA-COMMIT-N>
```

Repeat for all branches you need

Comment: Hi I want to Keep the branch alive I want to push all changes I made on my master branch into my other branches aswell

Comment: @Jonnotdoexx both approaches will keep your branches separate and master intact and unaware of their changes.

Comment: ok I think I got confused since the gui is showing the other branch in the same "line" as the master but that is ok since ist the same codebase

Comment: Look at the commit tree, you should be able to figure out if the correct commits are in the right branches just by following the nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can use cherry pick to move your commits

Comment: Not move, copy.